# Is it possible to nest media queries within media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

Is this possible? It seems like a neat solution to me, but I'm not sure if it will work.

```css
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

    /* Code for both portrait and landscape */

    @media (orientation:portrait) {

        /* Code for just portrait */

    }

    @media (orientation:landscape) {

        /* Code for just landscape */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should be able to [nest `@media` rules this way in CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing), but it isn't yet supported by most browsers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nested-css-media-queries/11747166#11747166) for details.

You would have to fully expand and repeat the top-level media queries for the inner rules for it to work across browsers (and I imagine the SCSS processor would generate something similar):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* Code for both portrait and landscape */
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px) 
and (orientation: portrait) {

    /* Code for just portrait */

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px) 
and (orientation: landscape) {

    /* Code for just landscape */

}
```

Comment: As of the time this comment was written, [all browsers, except IE11, support nesting media queries](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries).

Comment: @Qasim: The link here points to a more up-to-date one stating that this is now supported in all browsers; this answer is now obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this the best way is to use the high level media query in a link tag, and then the other queries inside the linked sheet.

In practice though most people cascade their CSS rules from a base sheet that covers the common stuff and then putting changes to that in each media rule-set.

Comment: I like this idea, as it technically does nesting as implied.

Answer (score 2):

I think not possible but you can write this format If you are using SASS css pre-processor.

example , you can copy this code and paste to https://www.sassmeister.com/ -and watch the output

**SASS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body{
    color:red;
  }
   @media (orientation:portrait) {
       body{
        color:green;
      }
   }
   @media (orientation:landscape) {
       body{
        color:orange;
      }
   }
}
```

**Output CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    color: green;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    color: orange;
  }
}
```