# Combining CSS media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to display the same set of CSS styles to people printing the page (media=print) and people browsing on a mobile phone. Is there a way I can combine CSS media queries?

Something like

```
@media only print or @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #container {
    width: 480px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668301/is-it-possible-to-embed-media-queries-within-media-queries

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Separate them with a comma:

```
@media only print, only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

[See the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0), in particular, example VI (emphasis added):

> Several media queries can be combined in a media query list. A
>   comma-separated list of media queries. If one or more of the media
>   queries in the comma-separated list are true, the whole list is true,
>   and otherwise false. In the media queries syntax, **the comma expresses
>   a logical OR**, while the ‘and’ keyword expresses a logical AND.

I doubt that the second `only` is needed, so you can probably do:

```
@media only print, screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

Comment: The "only" operator is used to apply a style only if the entire query matches, useful for preventing older browsers from applying selected styles. So just use comma...

eg: if you want to apply a style when the device is in landscape mode:

@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }

Answer (score 4):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

> You can combine multiple media queries in a comma-separated list; if
>   any of the media queries in the list is true, the associated style
>   sheet is applied.  This is the equivalent of a logical "or" operation.

You just have to remove the second `@media` and add some brackets.