# How combine multiple media destinations (screen, print) with width restriction?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to use some css files for both screen and print, but restrict them by width. How do I do this?

Is this correct?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(screen, print) and (min-width: 64em)" href="large.css" />
```

or this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(screen or print) and (min-width: 64em)" href="large.css" />
```

or is it something else?

Comment: Have you tried them? What do your experiments show?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Neither works. This doesn't work either: `only screen and (min-width: 64em),only print and (min-width: 64em)` nor does this: `screen and (min-width: 64em),print and (min-width: 64em)`

Comment: It's [not possible to combine media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax). At best, you could s[eparate each media queries with a comma `,`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994664/combining-css-media-queries)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing the statements rather than combining them works for me...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 64em), print and (min-width: 64em)" href="large.css" />
```