# Mobile device responsive design layout

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've just moved from native iOS dev to cross platform. I'm using phonegap and I would like to create different layouts based on device screen size and orientation.
What I would like to do is something similar to this code

```
if(orientation == LANDSCAPE)
{
    if(screen.width < 320)
    {
        //use css #1
    }
    else
    {
        //use css #2
    }
}
else //orientation is PORTRAIT
{
    if(screen.width < 320)
    {
        //use css #3
    }
    else
    {
        //use css #4
    }
}
```

Or if it's not the appropriate way to do design, then how do I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to compare the screen width? Is it for comparing iPod/iPhone against iPad? Or, is it for another reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strogly depends on what you want to do. If you intend to change the logic or add/remove elements from the DOM based on device's resolution or screen orientation, then go with the JS way. If you're using jQuery it's as simple, as that:

```
var deviceWidth = $(window).width();
var deviceHeight = $(window).height();
```

Yet, CSS itself provides the way for conditional styles depending on screen size. These are called `media-queries` ( http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ ) and you can use them as follows:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body {
        font-size: 2em;
        /* etc. these styles will be applied only when device's screen is smaller than 480px */
    }
}
```

There are many more properties which you can use. `max-device-width` is just and example.
Moreover you can prevent the browser from loading the style file at all if the device's size is not proper:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width-device: 480px)" href="480-device.css" />
```

Look at the w3c documentation or just search for `media-queries`. They're compatible with almost every browser now: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Answer (score 0):

Given that PhoneGap wraps Web apps into a native shell, you are essentially doing Web development at this point. You need to look into [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). For the code you published, the appropriate media queries would look similar to the following:

```
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}

/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}

/* Portrait and screen width < 320 */
@media screen 
and (orientation: portrait)
and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Portrait styles for screen smaller than 320 pixels */
}
```

The media query specification says you should be able to nest media queries, that would more closely match the structure of your control statements, but [unfortunately most modern browsers do not yet support this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668301/is-it-possible-to-embed-media-queries-within-media-queries).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try the following JS code:

```
function _orientationHandler() {
    if(event.orientation){
        if(event.orientation == 'portrait'){
            if(screen.width < 320)
            {
                //use css #1
            }
            else
            {
                //use css #2
            }
    }
    else if(event.orientation == 'landscape') {
        if(screen.width < 320)
        {
            //use css #1
        }
        else
        {
            //use css #2
        }
    }
}

$(window).bind('orientationchange', _orientationHandler);
```