# Media queries for ie only

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Ie is being weird again.

Our team is trying to add some styles for ie only so resize some text that lays on an image. The first ms-high-contrast works however all the following media queries fail. Is there a better more eloquent way to do this?

We're at a loss. What's up with ie?

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .homebox .mdlogolg{
        left: -60px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) {
        .homebox .mdlogolg{
            left: -60px;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
        .homebox .mdlogolg{
            left: -36px;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .homebox .mdlogolg{
            left: -25px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try unnesting the queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668301/is-it-possible-to-nest-media-queries-within-media-queries

Comment: @Lucas but it has to be for ie only.

Comment: you can add the ie only query inside your subqueries, using 'and', see the answer from my link for an example

Comment: @Lucas, that has been tried. Ie will not process them

Comment: see this fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/0kc3dbmL/2/

Comment: I posted an answer you can try this also check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the above by separating those media queries (because, nesting won't work). Try the following code...

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .homebox .mdlogolg{
        left: -60px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .homebox .mdlogolg{
        left: -36px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (max-width: 767px) and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .homebox .mdlogolg{
        left: -25px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no media queries for IE, but you can create separate stylesheet for IE with all properties and he will apply automatically, if it IE.

```
<head>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) might help you.
Also, you can watch at [code example](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) of `Bootstrap`, what they invent for IE supporting.